# Error: Could not find or load main class Orders

Tags: java, json, debugging, visual-studio-code, launch

So I have a folder where some files are sitting. One PDF (the homework assignment), one .vscode folder with the Launch.json inside for debugging, and 3 .java files.

These files are: Orders.java, Truck.java, and Car.java

Truck and Car contain classes, Orders contains the main program:

```
public class Orders {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //actual program inside
    }
}
```

I used VS Code's gear button in the debugger pane to create the launch.json, which gave me this for a launch option:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Launch)-Orders",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "Orders",
        "args": ""
    },
```

I set some breakpoints hoping to be off to the races. However when I hit the green play button to run the program, I get the error listed in the title of the post: `Error: Could not find or load main class Orders`

Is there something wrong with Launch.json or is there something else that could be causing this issue?

Also, if I run the program in the VS Code provided terminal:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
d.

PS C:\Users\Profile Name\Documents\RIT\Fall 2017\ISTE 200\HW\HW3> java Orders
```

The program runs fine but hits no breakpoints.

I'm using the Redhat Java Support extension, if that matters.

Comment: Does the Orders class have a package declaration at the top of the file?

Comment: It does not. Line 1 is an import statement for the Scanner class (`import java.util.Scanner;`).  Line 2 is `public class Orders {`

Comment: It should be `javac Orders` (java compiler) as opposed to `java` - the runtime, JVM. `javac -cp . Orders` for the class path.

Comment: Try setting the `cwd` option in `launch.json` to be equal to the fully qualified path to your java code. Ex: add a line like: `"cwd" = "C:\Users\me\HW\"`

Comment: @RickRidley added `"cwd": "C:/Users/Profile Name/Documents/RIT/Fall 2017/ISTE 200/HW/HW3/"` but it still produces the same error message. I'm trying to look at ways to mess with the configuration.  However I don't know if there's something I can do to the files in jGrasp that could help like making them into a project or package, since you asked about the package earlier.

Comment: Since you're on windows (presumably), you should be using `\ ` instead of `/` in your path specification. (Backward vs. forward slash). See if that resolves your problem. If not, I have some other suggestions.

Comment: @RickRidley yes I'm on Windows. I changed them to backslashes and that gives some green and red lines under the text, `Property cwd is not allowed
` and `Unexpected end of string`. Using forwardslashes gets rid of the second one but not the first. Also, still the same error message. Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: you might need to change it to Orders.java? Idk im just throwing out ideas, I dont run on VS